# Inserting data that is returned by calling a web service into SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, web-services

I have created a web service client that calls the web service and returns the response. Now I have to insert that data into SQL server db. I am new to java and so need suggestions on how to do it. Can someone please share the link to a example or other procedures that explains this.

Edit:(Adding snippet from my code)

```
    try {
        stub = new WebServiceStub();
        res6 = stub.getFile(getFile);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayOfAttachmentData attach = res6.getFileResult().getAttachmentData();
    AttachmentData[] attachment = attach.getAttachmentData();
    for(int i=0;i<attachment.length;i++){


        System.out.println("Attachment:" + i);

        System.out.println("DateCreated:" + attachment[i].getCreateDate());
        System.out.println("FileName:" + attachment[i].getFilename());
        System.out.println("FileSize" + attachment[i].getFileSize());
        System.out.println("FileSequence" + attachment[i].getSequence());
        System.out.println("FileType" + attachment[i].getType());

    }
```

Now how can i add all the dates,filenames,fileseqs,filetypes in my SQL Server table?

Thanks

Comment: please do some search yourself in google to find some examples

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://bit.ly/17Y5fbG)

Comment: I know how to insert data. But I don't know how to insert the data in a loop. By calling that web service, I get arrays, schemas and also normal strings. So I am confused how to do that one.

Answer (score 0):

This is little big for comment, You have to create Database, if you not already in sql server, and Table Structure to store data which you received from Web Service in Database. Create connection in your Java program and Follow [article](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0002) to go through.

Inserting data into an SQL database table with JDBC is a simple two-step process. Just

(1) create a Statement object, and

(2) use the object to run your normal SQL INSERT commands.

As per my suggestion, do some research. if you are new in programming.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer but I know how to insert data. What I don't know is inserting the data that is returned by calling web service. I have few questions here. 
1. Do i need to store the returned data somewhere and then insert it into the db? or can i directly call the client methods while inserting the data?
2. That service returns data in the form of arrays, schemas, and also strings. How do i insert all this data using loops? 
I tried Google but everyone showed how to insert normal data using insert command. Here the data is in bulk and more data keeps on adding.

Comment: Answer to your questions  1) Storeing and then insert in DB or directly insert, both depends what is your requirements, you can choose either way  2) Second thing you have to think, how you are going to store data in database which is returned from WebService, what is your table structure, You can discuss with your DBA to handle this or ask separate question for what will be your upcoming DataBase Structure.   Once you decide both these question, then You can do all insert in easy ways, but first need to choose which way then choose How